# Probability: $5$ stand in a line and $2$ stand together

Tags: probability

A group of $5$ consists of $3$ girls and $2$ boys. If the group of $5$ stand in a line what is the probability that the boys stand together? Help please, with reasoning!

Comment: Each child is distinct.  In how many ways can the children stand in a line?  In how many ways can the boys stand together?  The first question I ask should be routine.  The second one, if still stuck, clump the boys up.  Pick where the clump goes in relation to the girls (bb g g g, or g bb g g, or ...).  Then figure out who was who.  Reason finally that since each arrangement is presumably equally likely to occur, the probability is the ratio of "good" arrangements to total arrangements.

Comment: Assuming the children are distinct: $5!$ ways to order the children in total, and of those, $4$ places to stick a pair of boys, $2!$ ways to order those boys, and $3!$ ways to order the girls, so $4 \cdot 3! \cdot 2! / 5! = 2/5$

Comment: $8\cdot 3! /5!$

Comment: @ArukaJ I understand why you use the term "distinct". In real world setting the assumption sounds weird. As if it could happen that children that are not distinct :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A group of 5 consists of 3 girls and 2 boys. If the group of 5 stand in a line what is the probability that the boys stand together?

So, the quotient we're looking for is:
$$
\frac{\text{# ways for boys to stand together}}{\text{# total possible arrangements}}
$$

The denominator is simple: we have $5$ people, so there are $5!$ ways to arrange them (without restriction).

For the numerator: We want the two boys to stand together.  Thus, we may treat the two boys standing side-by-side as if they were a single person.  So, we have $4$ "things" we need to arrange (3 girls, and then one "two-boy-combo"), for a total of $4!$ arrangements.  ***However***, the order of the boys is important, too!  Since, for every arrangement we've counted above, we can arrange the boys in two ways, there are $4!\cdot 2$ ways of forming lines with the two boys adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the product:

(# ways to place 2 boys together in the line) (# ways to distribute the reamining 3 children in the remaining vacancies in the line).

Answer (score 0):

Start with $5$ open spots where the boys and girls will be located.

There are $\binom52=10$ ways to select $2$ spots for the boys.

Under the extra condition that the boys must stand together there are $4$ ways to select $2$ spots for the boys.

So we arrive at probability: $$\frac4{10}$$

Essential of this approach is that irrelevant things such as the names of the children are modded out. The only thing that really counts is the gender.